# How do I make a Google Sheet Chart (gauge) to display the last row of data?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm sending data from a IOT device to a google sheet. Every few seconds a new row is made with a timestamp and temperature value.

I want to make a gauge chart that shows the most recent value submitted. However, when I go to choose the range for the gauge, I can only choose from specific cells.... I'm not allowed to select the "last" row, as that keeps changing.

I believe there is a way to do this with a google apps script, but need help. Any tips on how to have a gauge with a range of the last line submitted?

Comment: Hi, are you asking if I've considered having the IOT device posting it's latest value in the same cell on the Sheet? I have, but haven't done simply because I am not sure how to....  I don't know enough JS to change but would try something if you have a recommendation..

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna write you a code snippet with valid sample format. For this sample to work, you must follow my sheet format as is.
 There is no ad-hoc Apps Script method to do this where you call the method and boom everything is done. You have to code it.

```
 function getLastRowValues(){ 
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_ID");
     var myArray = ss.getRange("A1:B").getValues();

      loop1:
      for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
            loop2:
            for(var j = 0; j <myArray[i].length; j++){
                  if(myArray[i][j] === ""){ 

                      //DO SOMETHING WITH THE VALUES FROM LAST ROWS..in this case
                      //I'm just printing them in the Logger.log
                      Logger.log("last Timestamp is " + myArray[i-1][j]);
                      Logger.log("last Temperature is " + myArray[i-1][j+1]);
                      break loop1;
                  }

              }
            }
}
```

Sample Sheet:

[image]

**Output:**

```
[18-01-07 ] last Timestamp is a5
[18-01-07 ] last Temperature is b5
```

Let's say new values were added:

[image]

**Output:**

```
[18-01-07 ] last Timestamp is a9
[18-01-07 ] last Temperature is b9
```

*And so forth..* This function scans the whole A & B columns and stops if it encounters an empty cell then fetches the last values in the sheet.

It would help a lot to learn Javascript and Apps Script [Class SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) so you can write your own implementations as well.

Comment: Excellent Noogui! Thank you.  I see the correct last entry is being shown in the log. My goal is to use this data to display readings in a gauge chart. Can you please show me how to put the output of this into it's own cell, so I can easily graph it?   (Yes, I agree, on learning JS! I'm studying currently.)

Comment: I'll leave that to you. You can use [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) for putting data into cells.

Answer (score 0):

OP insists on GAS, but others may be more flexible:

[image: animated gauge]

Comment: pnuts, thanks for your response. I don't understand what the acronyms "OP" or "GAS" are. Can you elaborate plz?